# How to create where by list of complex clauses?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a list of objects `List<(int id1, int id2)>` and I need to build LINQ, which makes the same as this SQL

```
SELECT Id1, Id2, SomeColumn
  FROM SomeTable
  WHERE (Id1 = 1 AND Id2 = 2) OR
        (Id1 = 1 AND Id2 = 3)
```

I figured out that I should use expressions, but I can't understand how to do it.

```
Expression expression = Expression.Empty();
foreach (var requestInfo in requestInfos)
{
    Expression<Func<SomeDto, bool>> buf = i => i.Id1 == requestInfo.Id1 && i.Id2 == requestInfo.Id2;
    expression = Expression.OrElse(expression, buf);
}

var query = _context.SomeTable.Where(expression);
```

Comment: can u please show us the List<objects> you want to Filter ?

Comment: @IbraHimM.Nada let it be `List<(int id1, int id2, string someColumn)>` Does it matter?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, you need to call your expression `buf` before you can `OrElse`. Then you can wrap all into a Lambda-Expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, this sounds like a case where you would want to make use of a PredicateBuilder

Details on that [Here](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

In essence though it would leave you doing something like

```
var predicate = ProdicateBuilder.False<SomeDTO>();
foreach (var requestInfo in requestInfos)
{
   predicate = predicate.Or(i=>  i.Id1 == requestInfo.Id1 && i.Id2 == requestInfo.Id2);
}
```

and then within your where clause you just pass in the predicate.

Equally, it also details how to use Expressions directly over at that link, if you wanted to do that as opposed to adding the PredicateBuilder code to your work.

Comment: Hope I will find a time for this book.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to build it like this

```
var requestInfos = new List<(int Id1, int Id2)>();
requestInfos.Add((1, 2));
requestInfos.Add((1, 3));

var someTable = new List<(int Id1, int Id2, string someColumn)>();
someTable.Add((1, 2, "12"));
someTable.Add((2, 2, "22"));
someTable.Add((1, 3, "13"));

var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof((int Id1, int Id2, string someColumn)));
Expression body = Expression.Constant(true);
foreach (var requestInfo in requestInfos)
{
    var tableId1 = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, typeof((int Id1, int Id2, string someColumn)).GetMember("Item1")[0]);
    var tableId2 = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, typeof((int Id1, int Id2, string someColumn)).GetMember("Item2")[0]);
    var paramId1 = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(Expression.Constant(requestInfo), typeof((int Id1, int Id2)).GetMember("Item1")[0]);
    var paramId2 = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(Expression.Constant(requestInfo), typeof((int Id1, int Id2)).GetMember("Item2")[0]);
    var and = Expression.And(Expression.Equal(paramId1, tableId1), Expression.Equal(paramId2, tableId2));
    body = Expression.OrElse(body, and);
    Expression<Func<(int Id1, int Id2, string someColumn), bool>> buf = i => i.Id1 == requestInfo.Id1 && i.Id2 == requestInfo.Id2;
}
var func = Expression.Lambda<Func<(int Id1, int Id2, string someColumn), bool>>(body, new[] {parameter});

var query = someTable.AsQueryable().Where(func);
```

Still this is quite complicated and gets out of hand quickly. The Predicate Builder (also mentioned by Gibbon's answer) should be a more scalable approach

Answer (score 0):

If you want the really simple answer:

```
_context.SomeTable.Where(x => x.Id1 == 1 && (x.Id2 == 2 || x.Id2 == 3));
```

However I'm assuming your case probably won't be that simple, you can create a list of Ids that it should match and use like so:

```
var id1s = new List<int>{ 1 };
var id2s = new List<int>{ 2, 3 };
_context.SomeTable.Where(x => id1s.Contains(x.Id1) && id2s.Contains(x.Id2));
```

Comment: First example is joke :-) Second will give me the incorrect result.

Comment: @Nodon - Why is the first example a joke?

Answer (score 0):

i think this could may help you

```
var emails = _userManager.Users
.Where(user => user.CustomerId == null)
.Select(user => user.Email) // extract the emails from users
.ToList();

var customers = _applicationRepository.GetCustomers()
.Where(customer => emails.Contains(customer.Email)) // the Contains method carry the IN logic when translated to SQL script
.ToList();
```

Comment: It works only if I have a simple clause per single column. In my case, I am using two columns at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Value Tuples this would be the answer :

```
    List<(int id1, int id2,string someColumn)> your_List= new List<(int id1, int id2, string someColumn)>();
    var your_Data= your_List.Where(x => (x.id1 == 1 && x.id2 == 2) || (x.id1 == 1 && x.id2 == 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use like this:

```
List<(int id1, int id2)> list = new List<(int id1, int id2)>() { (1, 2), (10, 2), (1, 20), (1, 3), (2, 2), (1, 2) /* more data */ };

var result = list.Where(x => (x.id1 == 1 && x.id2 == 2) || (x.id1 == 1 && x.id2 == 3));
```

I've tried it with my own sample data.

[image]